# Resolving variables in scope modified by Scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm investigating the possibility to make the following kind of imports compile
in Scala:

```
def helpers[T] = new { def foo: T = ??? }
import helpers[Int]._
```

This arose as an idea to pin down some types that Scala could
not infer on its own.
A manually expanded version works:

```
val m = helpers[Int]
import m._
(foo: Int)
```

However, my naive attempt at a macro failed:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object Open {
  def open[T](m: Any)(t: T): T = macro open_impl[T]

  def open_impl[T](c: Context)(m: c.Tree)(t: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val freshName = TermName(c.freshName("import$"))
    q"{ val $freshName = $m; import $freshName._; $t }"
  }
}
```

The syntax I had in mind was the `let open M in`-syntax from OCaml.
Problem being that the binding of variables seems to happen before the
macro expansion:

```
import Open._
object Foo { val x = 7 }
open(Foo) { println(x) }
```

fails in the REPL with:

```
<console>:16: error: not found: value x
       open(Foo) { println(x) }
```

Any ideas how to work around this? Is it at all possible with macros?
Or perhaps with a compiler plugin?

Comment: the `import $freshName._` is expanded inside internal subscope. You can think of whole def macro result as of bunch of code, defined inside the `{...}`

Comment: Knowing that all the expressions are defined inside `class`es, `trait`s, `object`s or `def`s you can define macro annotation that will take some names as parameters and rewrite annotated body, importing content of named things as soon as they defined

Comment: @Odomontois Incorrect. This is a blackbox macro, what you said is only *sort-of* true for whitebox macros. The macro takes as argument the expression to "open" in, so that argument is inside the macro's purview, and your complaint wouldn't be a problem even if the macro was whitebox. The real issue is that macros have to run after the typer. The typer tries to type `{ println(x) }`, notices `x` doesn't exist because macros haven't run yet, and then dies. You can see it if you add `-Ybrowse:all` or `-Xprint:all` to the compiler args.